# How to recognize diagonal swipes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, swipe-gesture, gesturedetector, gesture-detection

I attempted to detect diagonal swipe direction using `GestureDetector`. I used the `onPanStart` method to detect the screen's corners.
However, it is not perfect because it only considers the beginning of the gesture.

Right now, if I swipe bottom left to top right in the top right corner or part, it gives me the incorrect top right direction. In this case, the correct direction should be bottom left.

So, how can we identify diagonal swipe direction using `GestureDetector` or any other method?

I looked at several other StackOverflow posts, but they only detect top, left, right, and bottom directions.

Here is an example of code.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    String? swipeDirection;

    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: GestureDetector(
          child: Container(),
          onPanStart: (details) {
            final halfScreenWidth = screenSize.width / 2;
            final halfScreenHeight = screenSize.height / 2;
            final position = details.localPosition;

            if ((position.dx < halfScreenWidth) &&
                (position.dy < halfScreenHeight)) {
              swipeDirection = 'topLeft';
            } else if ((position.dx > halfScreenWidth) &&
                (position.dy < halfScreenHeight)) {
              swipeDirection = 'topRight';
            } else if ((position.dx < halfScreenWidth) &&
                (position.dy > halfScreenHeight)) {
              swipeDirection = 'bottomLeft';
            } else {
              swipeDirection = 'bottomRight';
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pan update to find the position of the pointer the same manner you did for pan start and get the starting and ending points. Then on pan end execute with the final results

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHome> createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  String? swipeStart;
  String? swipeEnd;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          onPanStart: (details) {
            final halfScreenWidth = screenSize.width / 2;
            final halfScreenHeight = screenSize.height / 2;
            final position = details.localPosition;

            if ((position.dx < halfScreenWidth) &&
                (position.dy < halfScreenHeight)) {
              swipeStart = 'topLeft';
            } else if ((position.dx > halfScreenWidth) &&
                (position.dy < halfScreenHeight)) {
              swipeStart = 'topRight';
            } else if ((position.dx < halfScreenWidth) &&
                (position.dy > halfScreenHeight)) {
              swipeStart = 'bottomLeft';
            } else {
              swipeStart = 'bottomRight';
            }
            // print(swipeStart);
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            final halfScreenWidth = screenSize.width / 2;
            final halfScreenHeight = screenSize.height / 2;
            final position = details.localPosition;

            if ((position.dx < halfScreenWidth) &&
                (position.dy < halfScreenHeight)) {
              swipeEnd = 'topLeft';
            } else if ((position.dx > halfScreenWidth) &&
                (position.dy < halfScreenHeight)) {
              swipeEnd = 'topRight';
            } else if ((position.dx < halfScreenWidth) &&
                (position.dy > halfScreenHeight)) {
              swipeEnd = 'bottomLeft';
            } else {
              swipeEnd = 'bottomRight';
            }
            //print(swipeEnd);
          },
          onPanEnd: (details) {
            print("Final direction was from $swipeStart to $swipeEnd");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have printed output like this

```
flutter: Final direction was from topLeft to bottomRight
flutter: Final direction was from bottomLeft to topRight
```

**EDIT**

You can find the offset when the pan starts and updates. Then on pan end calculate the direction like this

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHome> createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  String? horizontalDirection;
  String? verticalDirection;
  late Offset startPoint;
  late Offset endPoint;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          onPanStart: (details) {
            startPoint = details.localPosition;
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            endPoint = details.localPosition;
          },
          onPanEnd: (details) {
            if (startPoint.dx < endPoint.dx) {
              horizontalDirection = "right";
            } else {
              horizontalDirection = "left";
            }

            if (startPoint.dy < endPoint.dy) {
              verticalDirection = "bottom";
            } else {
              verticalDirection = "top";
            }
            print("Final direction was $horizontalDirection$verticalDirection");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for answering. It will not work if the swipe length (translation) is small. You can just try swiping from the bottom left to the top right in the top right corner. it will print ```flutter: Final direction was from topLeft to topLeft```

Comment: Updated my answer. This method will work on any part of the screen and even if the swipe length is very small

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the `GestureDetector` widget there isn't any kind of feature your'e searching for. Also there is no other widget in my mind which is able to do that.

Maybe you can try to add the following:
Save the position of the `onPanStart` of one of the directions. Add `onPanEnd` and do the exact same you did for `onPanStart` and also save these positions. Now add `onPanUpdate` and with this you will compare the first and last point which was recognized. If you are working with screensizes as I can see, you can divide your screen in 4 blocks (top, left, right, bottom) and with the informations of the first and last position you can detect the diagonal swipe

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I had a similar idea in my mind. I m looking if it is an easy way to detect this. I will try and update you. Thank You.